# Excel INDEX MATCH to another file to dynamic location by header name without Table References

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, vlookup, index-match

I have 2 files.
On the first file I have a table with ID column and other columns as well. in the "Messi" column I want to INDEX MATCH to get the value "5" for when ID = "AAA".
notice that the second file is not a table and also that the columns in the second file are not in the same order as the first file.

any help please?

**First File:**
[image]

**Second File:**

[image]

Comment: What is exactly the issue? You can use for that `INDEX/XMATCH` for example. Share in the question the formula you are trying to use and the error or the wrong result you are getting. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cell B5 of your First File:

```
=INDEX('[Second File.xlsx]Second File'!$C:$C, MATCH($A5, '[Second File.xlsx]Second File'!$A:$A,0))
```

`Index/Match` syntax for column lookup:

```
=INDEX([Result Column], MATCH([Lookup Cell], [Lookup Column], [Match Type]))
```

Using that I'm sure you'll be able to figure out which columns and cells you'll need to change to get the results for the other cells :)

**EDIT**: If you want to have the look up of the column headers then I suggest the below formula as it doesn't rely on `INDIRECT` which would only work when the second workbook is open:

```
=INDEX('[Second File.xlsx]Second File'!$A:$D, MATCH($A5, '[Second File.xlsx]Second File'!$A:$A,0), MATCH(B$4, '[Second File.xlsx]Second File'!$4:$4,0))
```

What's different:

- The first parameter in the `INDEX` function covers the entire table `'[Second File.xlsx]Second File'!$A:$D`
- There is a third parameter added in the `INDEX` function to look up the column header. `MATCH(B$4, '[Second File.xlsx]Second File'!$4:$4,0)`

  - `B$4` looks up the column header
  - `'[Second File.xlsx]Second File'!$4:$4` is where it looks at

Comment: That was the issue that I didn't know that the column i was searching for was column C. anyway I took it a couple of steps further and I found the answer I was looking for:

=@INDIRECT("'[Second File.xlsx]Second File'!" & ADDRESS(MATCH([@ID],'[Second File.xlsx]Second File'!$A:$A,0),MATCH("Lionel Messi",'[Second File.xlsx]Second File'!$1:$1,0)))

I can even find the Header rows in both sheets if I tried to. But this was the answer I was looking for. I hope it can help someone else too.

Comment: I added a new formula which doesn't use `INDIRECT` which only works when you have the second workbook open

Comment: Kairu how would you keep the format of that good formula you've added but add another MATCH - let's say I don't know in which column to look for $A5.

Answer (score 0):

I took it a couple of steps further and I found the answer I was looking for:

```
=@INDIRECT("'[Second File.xlsx]Second File'!" & ADDRESS(MATCH([@ID],'[Second File.xlsx]Second File'!$A:$A,0),MATCH("Lionel Messi",'[Second File.xlsx]Second File'!$1:$1,0)))
```

I can even find the Header rows in both sheets if I tried to. But this was the answer I was looking for. I hope it can help someone else too.